# Android Translucent activity don't get touch at the start

Tags: android, styles, touch, transparent

I'm using style to start a translucent activity after long click.
the problem is that bottom activity get the touch until user pick up his finger from the screen. after the user pick up finger and press again, the top activity get touches. 
Any idea how to make top activity get touches from beginning?

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>


</style>
```

And my activity:

```
public class GroupDragForArchive extends BaseActivity {

private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures";

@Override
protected int getLayoutId() {
    return R.layout.drag;
}

@Override
public boolean shouldBeLoggedInForActivity() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean shouldPollInActivity() {
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

}

public static void startActivity(Activity activity) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, GroupDragForArchive.class);
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, IntConst.RequestCodes.REQUEST_DRAG_FOR_ARCHIVE);
    activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

}

@Override
protected int getPayBoxTheme() {
    return R.style.Theme_Transparent;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

    switch(action) {
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was MOVE");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was UP");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Movement occurred outside bounds " +
                    "of current screen element");
            return true;
        default :
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

on my bottom activity i have recycler view that holds views from type of frame layout. in frame layout i open the second activity on that way:

```
    setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        Context context = mRecycler.getContext();
        GroupDragForArchive.startActivity((Activity)context);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you share the code where you declaring onLongPress to start activity?

Comment: @Anmol I've add it to the question